# Check if an item exists then replace it in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

how do i check if an item exists and if it does replace it in NSMutableArray i just cant figure it out all i have so far is:

```
int i = [arrayOne indexOfObject:@"object to replace"];
    NSLog(@"%@", i);
    [arrayOne replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"replace"];
```

but i keep getting errors :S can anyone help me ?

My array is:

```
@[ "13L6-A67-1", "13NAPUSD-A1", "13NASUWO-X1", "13NASUWO-X1", "13ASECON-D1", "13ASECON-D1", "13ASECON-D1", "13ASECON-D1", "13ASMATH-C1", "13ASMATH-C1", "13ASMATH-C1", "13ASMATH-C1", "13ASPHYS-B1", "13ASPHYS-B1", "13ASPHYS-B1", "13ASPHYS-B1", "13B3ITCE-F1", "13B3ITCE-F1", "13B3ITCE-F1", "13B3ITCE-F1" ]
```

Comment: Give details of the error. Show an example of what your array contains and what you try to replace a specific item.

Comment: @Wain this is my array "13L6-A67-1",
        "13NAPUSD-A1",
        "13NASUWO-X1",
        "13NASUWO-X1",
        "13ASECON-D1",
        "13ASECON-D1",
        "13ASECON-D1",
        "13ASECON-D1",
        "13ASMATH-C1",
        "13ASMATH-C1",
        "13ASMATH-C1",
        "13ASMATH-C1",
        "13ASPHYS-B1",
        "13ASPHYS-B1",
        "13ASPHYS-B1",
        "13ASPHYS-B1",
        "13B3ITCE-F1",
        "13B3ITCE-F1",
        "13B3ITCE-F1",
        "13B3ITCE-F1" However this array will vary every time the app loads as it is retrieving the users data and parsing it from json into arrays

Comment: @JordanNewton - note that there are duplicate entries in your array so indexOfObject will return the index of first object in such cases. You may consider using NSSet instead of array. However, what error you are getting?

Comment: The return value of `indexOfObject:` is of type `NSUInteger`, not `int`. Use the correct type to get the proper result. And note that you can't call `replaceObjectAtIndex:` on an `NSArray`. You need an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @rmaddy it is a NSMutableArray

Comment: @JordanNewton Then what is the actual (and complete) error?

Comment: @rmaddy i dont have an error now it just wont replace the object i am trying to make it replace all the objects that say 13ASECON-D1 with a different value

Comment: @Ashok isn't an NSSet unordered ? i need it to be ordered as it will be used to populate a UITableView with different labels.

Comment: @JordanNewton Your question states that you keep getting errors.

Comment: @rmaddy i was until i took your advise and changed int to NSUInteger now it will run in the simulator just wont change any of the values

Answer (score 1):

if object is not present in array NSNotFound value is returned, so you need to check for it:

```
if (i != NSNotFound)
   [arrayOne replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"replace"];
```

Note also that if you want to print integer value, you should use `%d` format specifier, `%@` is used for objective-c objects

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are new to this platform. So here is the sample code that works -

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOne = [@[@"13L6-A67-1",@"13NAPUSD-A1",@"13NASUWO-X1",@"13NASUWO-X1",@"13ASECON-D1",@"13ASECON-D1",@"13ASECON-D1",@"13ASECON-D1",@"13ASMATH-C1",@"13ASMATH-C1",@"13ASMATH-C1",@"13ASMATH-C1",@"13ASPHYS-B1",@"13ASPHYS-B1",@"13ASPHYS-B1",@"13ASPHYS-B1",@"13B3ITCE-F1",@"13B3ITCE-F1",@"13B3ITCE-F1",@"13B3ITCE-F1" ] mutableCopy];

NSUInteger index = [arrayOne indexOfObject:@"13ASECON-D1"];

if (index != NSNotFound) {
    [arrayOne replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@"DIFFERENT_VALUE"];

    NSLog(@"arrayOne after replaceObjectAtIndex = %@", arrayOne);
}
```

General guidelines -

1. watch out for compiler warning when you build.
2. put breakpoint and step through your code which doesn't work.